# Deduce all but one template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a simple "Skip Iterator" with a template parameter for the number of elements to skip:

```
template <typename T, typename Iter, int Skip>
class SkipIterator
{
public:
    SkipIterator(Iter baseIter) :
        baseIter_(baseIter)
    {
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        baseIter_ += Skip;
    }

    T &operator*()
    {
        return *baseIter_;
    }

private:
    Iter baseIter_;
};
```

I'd like to be able to deduce the base `Iter` and `T` types like this:

```
std::vector<double> dataFromSomewhere;
SkipIterator<3> skipper(dataFromSomewhere.begin())
```

But the complier (VS2010) gives a "Too few template arguments" error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't deduce a template class's template arguments, so you have to specify all three anyway. You can get around that with a `make_skip_iterator` function that deduces `T` and `Iter`.

Comment: Please think about how to implement `end()`, which will not be not so easy, but very important.

Answer (score 8):

You can provide a helper function:

```
#include <iterator>

template <int Skip, typename Iter>
SkipIterator<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, Iter, Skip> 
    make_skip_iterator(Iter it)
{
    return SkipIterator<
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, Iter, Skip
        >(it);
}
```

Which you would use this way:

```
std::vector<double> dataFromSomewhere;
auto skipper = make_skip_iterator<3>(dataFromSomewhere.begin());
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a96591abbcbd371153c55a4a4f6924cd-25783dc5e0579471d3e326cae35dc982).

Notice, that the C++14 version of the above helper function would look nicer (at least in the signature) thanks to return type deduction:

```
template <int Skip, typename Iter>
auto make_skip_iterator(Iter it)
{
    return SkipIterator<
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, Iter, Skip
        >(it);
}
```

And the [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2cac25f2b4b9b076b69551214dab6b1f-25783dc5e0579471d3e326cae35dc982) of course.

Comment: This answer was really helpful, but I accepted Igor's because he needs the XP more :)

Comment: @japreiss: I don't have any problem with you accepting a better answer, as long as you do so because you consider it better. But answers should be accepted, upvoted, or downvoted not based on who is writing them (nice guy? annoying guy? low-rep-new-interesting-user vs high-rep-usual-guy? etc.), but based on their content. But apart from this, I don't have problems with your choice :)

Answer (score 6):

Template parameter deduction only happens in template function calls, never in variable declarations involving class template name. Also, if you want to deduce some but not all parameters, those you want deduced must be at the end.

All in all, you are looking for something like this:

```
template <int Skip, typename Iter>
auto make_skipper(Iter it)->SkptIterator<decltype(*it), Iter, Skip> {
  return SkptIterator<decltype(*it), Iter, Skip>(it);
}

auto skipper = make_skipper<3>(dataFromSomewhere.begin());
```